# Parsing Random Web Pages

Tags: html, parsing, html-parsing, text-processing

I need to parse a bunch of random pages and add them to a DB. I am thinking of using regular expressions but I was wondering if there are any 'special' techniques (other than looking for content between known text/tags). The content is more(not always) like:

```
Some Title
Text related to Title
```

I guess I don't need to extract complete Text but some way to know where the Title/Paragraph and extract the content from there. The content itself may have images/links that I would like to retain.

Thanks!

Comment: Quick, somebody link to that "don't parse HTML with regexs" rant!

Comment: Since HTML is almost XML, you could use any old XML parser to find the `/html/head/title` etc.

Comment: Since HTML can be ill-formed and still be tolerated by a browser, you'll be surprised at how bad it is.  An XML parser will often be baffled by broken XML and a regular expression can never work on practical HTML parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this answer: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Python.  http://www.python.org/
2. Use Beautiful Soup.  http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Comment: Thanks! I am planning to use a .NET.

Comment: @Venkateshwar: Please **update** your question with all the facts.  Python and Beautiful Soup work perfectly in .Net

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a proper HTML parser, and extract the elements you’re interested in via the parser’s API (or via the DOM).

Since I don’t know what language you’re programming in, it’s rather difficult to recommend a parser, but some well known ones are [Jericho](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html) for Java, and [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for Python.